# number-guessing game - 1 through 30

Tags: python, game, number-guessing-game

I created this python number-guessing game and I have two concerns with it. The code works as intended with no flaws; however, I'm not too fond of the way I wrote it. It is messy, unorganized, and all over the place. There is repeated code such as the while loop that checks for a negative number or a number greater than 30, and the repeating "if number == n".

I wrote it like that because the program would bug if I did not repeat those expressions.

I also want to make it ask the user if they would like to play again; I do not know how.

```
import random
n = random.randint(1, 31)

choice = input("\nDo you want to play a game? (y/n): ")
if (choice == "y") or (choice == "Y") or (choice == "Yes") or (choice == "yes"):

    counter = 0
    number = int(input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 30: "))
    if (number == n):
        print("\nYou guessed correctly!!! Go you!")
        counter += 1

    while (number < 1) or (number > 30):
        number = int(
            input("\nThat is an invalid number. Please re-enter a number between 1 and 30: "))
        if (number == n):
            print("\nYou guessed correctly!!! Go you!")

    while number != n:
        if (number <= 5) and (n > 5):
            number = int(input("\nToo low! Try again: "))
            counter += 1
        elif (number >= 25) and (n < 25):
            number = int(input("\nWay too high! Try again: "))
            counter += 1
        elif ((n + 5 >= number) and (n - 5 <= number)):
            number = int(input("\nYou are so close! Try again: "))
            counter += 1
        else:
            number = int(input("\nWrong! Try again: "))
            counter += 1
        if (number == n):
            print("\nYou guessed correctly!!! Go you!")
        while (number < 1) or (number > 30):
            number = int(
                input("\nThat is an invalid number. Please re-enter a number between 1 and 30: "))

    print(f"You took {counter} attempts to guess the number!")

else:
    print("\nYour loss....")
```

Comment: Do you know about functions? Have you tried using one to solve the duplication?

Answer (score 3):

### Bug

First off there's a minor bug in your code in that `random.randint(1, 31)` can be `31`, which you are not allowed to enter in your game. You probably want `random.randint(1, 30)`

### Naming

Your names are a little unhelpful. `n` should probably be something like `target`, `counter` `num_guesses` or similar. This makes it easier for someone coming along to easily identify what the variables actually mean.

### Structure

You take an initial guess, then have a second guess if the number is outside [1,30], then you have 2 `while`s one for the initial guess and one for subsequent ones. This is probably a little unnecessary.

For checking numbers we probably only need 2 loops. One to check while it's not the correct number, and another to get a valid input from the user.

We could just get the guess as a function!

```
def get_guess():
    """ Get valid input from player """
    while True:
        inp = input("Guess a number between 1 and 30: ")
        try:
            inp = int(inp)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Invalid value input {inp}, must be an integer between 1 and 30")
            continue
        if inp in range(1, 31):
            return inp

        print(f"Invalid value input {inp}, must be an integer between 1 and 30")


guesses = 0
while guesses < MAX_GUESSES:
    number = get_guess()
    if number <= 5 and n > 5:
        ...
```

### Use of ifs

Comparisons in Python can be chained to clean up a lot of checks.

```
if 0 < i < 31:
```

checks whether `i` is in the range [1, 30], you can also do `i in range(1,31)` which also makes your intent obvious.

In order to check how far you are from the correct answer, rather than checking the value of `n` and number separately, why not check if `number` is far from `n` by calculating the difference?

```
if abs(number - target) <= 5:  # Could just precompute the difference and compare it against each
    print("You're so close try again!")
elif number - target > 10:
    print("Way too high!")
elif number - target > 5:
    print("Too high!")
elif target - number > 10: # N.B. these are target - number i.e. number - target < -10
    print("Way too low!")
elif target - number > 5:
    print("Too low!")
```

In order to check whether choice is `y`,`Y`,`yes` or `Yes`, we could do:

```
if choice.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
```

which will case insensitively check.

### Replay

To answer your question on replaying the game, we need to wrap the whole thing in a `while` loop checking each time whether the player wants to play again, and generating a new number.

### Putting it all together

Putting it all together with main guards and functions we might end up with something like:

```
"""
Number guessing game
"""

import random


def get_guess():
    """ Get valid input from player """
    while True:
        inp = input("Guess a number between 1 and 30: ")
        try:
            inp = int(inp)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Invalid value input {inp}, must be an integer between 1 and 30")
            continue
        if inp in range(1, 31):
            return inp

        print(f"Invalid value input {inp}, must be an integer between 1 and 30")


def play_guess_game():
    """ Play a round of the guessing game """
    target = random.randint(1, 30)

    number = -1
    guesses = 0
    while number != target:
        guesses += 1
        number = get_guess()

        diff = number - target

        if diff == 0:
            print("You guessed correctly!!! Go you!")
        elif abs(diff) <= 5:
            print("You're so close try again!")
        elif diff > 10:
            print("Way too high!")
        elif diff > 5:
            print("Too high!")
        elif diff < -10:
            print("Way too low!")
        elif diff < -5:
            print("Too low!")

    print(f"You took {guesses} attempts to guess the number!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while input("Do you want to play a game? (y/[n]): ").lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
        play_guess_game()
    print("Your loss....")
```